# Let variables and block scope

Tags: ecmascript-6, let

Why does the first console log print out "James" when it should print out "Ken"? Shouldn't the let 'student' variable be scope to the 'if-statement' and retain its value as "Ken"? Also, shouldn't there be an error as I'm redeclaring the same variable name 'student'?

```
(function (){
    let student = {name: 'James'};
    function createStudent(name){
        if(true){
         let student = {name: name};
        }
        return student;
    }
    console.log(createStudent('Ken'));
    console.log(student);
})();
```

Comment: To log 'Ken', Use return statement inside if {} condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` is block scoped so this line of code:

```
let student = {name: name};
```

is scoped only to the brackets inside the `if` statement.  So, when you later do

```
return student;
```

outside of the `if` block and outside of where the other `student` variable was defined, that variable is no longer in scope so the only `student` variable that is in scope is the `James` one.

Here's an annotated version:

```
(function (){
    let student = {name: 'James'};
    function createStudent(name){
        if(true){
         // define new student variable that is only in scope
         // within this block
         let student = {name: name};
        }
        // here, the student variable on the previous line is no longer
        // in scope so referencing it here sees the first declaration
        return student;
    }
    console.log(createStudent('Ken'));
    console.log(student);
})();
```

> Shouldn't the let 'student' variable be scope to the 'if-statement' and retain its value as "Ken"?

It is block scoped to the `if` statement.   But, when you do the `return`, it's outside that block so there is no access to the `Ken` student variable any more so the only one that is in scope is the `James` one.

> Also, shouldn't there be an error as I'm redeclaring the same variable name 'student'?

It is not an error to define a variable that was already defined in a higher scope.  Instead, the new declaration shadows or hides the other declaration within that scope, temporarily overriding it within that scope.

Comment: thank you for your explanation about how returning a variable outside of an if-block, will reference the outer-scope's variable assignment.

As for your answer about why there isn't an error when redeclaring the same variable named 'student': "It is not an error to define a variable that was already defined in a higher scope."

I see an error here: 

`let a = 'bar';

function foo(){
 let a = 'baz';
 console.log(a);
    }
    console.log(a);`

Comment: never mind- for some reason, i saw an error when i typed this into the chrome console. But I went ahead on repl.it and it worked fine. Is it because the let variables are scoped differently? thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `let` and `const` unlike `var` create local scope inside block statements. You are not getting an error because the new variable
*shadows*
 the one outside the scope.